# Deleting blank lines to end of page

Tags: sed, gnu

I am trying to delete a file from the first blank line to the end of a .txt file. I am using the following line of code:

```
sed -i -b '/^$/,$d'
```

(taken almost directly from Unix Power Tools). In a multi-page document, this successfully deletes the second page of text, but still leaves the footer on the first page(see below *text slightly modified for space):

```
 29         0235600          Drain Pan   
 62         6151060          Nut, Serrated 5/16-18 Hex
            7003932  
 30         6201920          Screw, 8-15X2 6-Lobe PH                  
                             W/H Network Svce
 63  
 64         7003931          W/H Network Svce  
























                                                            4  
        #      1  - Revision D - February, 2007
         375844
             Previous Page              Main Menu           Model 648PRO Menu             Next Page
```

I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1

Any suggestions please.

Comment: "Page"? What is the format of this document? Can you delete lines to produce an example about a dozen lines long? And are you sure those are empty lines, and not some other whitespace?

Comment: Format of the doc is .txt. I think it's actually a UT-8. The example didn't come across as I had hoped. There are actually about a dozen blank lines between the to chunks of data. The editor shows them as CR LF on every line, as well as the end of every line with data.

Answer (score 1):

Those things at the end (`CR/LF`) are DOS style end-of-line characters. I don't know why the `-b` option isn't coping with them, but you can try this kludge:

```
sed -i '/^.$/,$d'
```